# ffmpeg error: Too large number of skipped frames xxxxx > 60000

Tags: ffmpeg, raspberry-pi2, fluent-ffmpeg

I try to record on RasperryPI from usb Cam (/dev/video0) using segments to obtain sliced video.
The command I'm using is:

```
ffmpeg -input_format mjpeg -video_size 640x480 -i /dev/video0 -y -y -f v4l2 -an -pix_fmt yuv420p -codec copy -f segment -segment_time 60 -segment_wrap 10 -t 180 stream/looper%02d.avi
```

I got an error after 2 minutes about skipped frames (see later for detail).
Is I run the same command without segmentation is working.

I tested on different HW, with different segment parameters, with different usb cam but the situation still the same.

Here there is the output:

```
   ffmpeg version 4.1.4-1+rpt1~deb10u1 Copyright (c) 2000-2019 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 8 (Raspbian 8.3.0-6+rpi1)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version='1+rpt1~deb10u1' --toolchain=hardened --libdir=/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf --incdir=/usr/include/arm-linux-gnueabihf --arch=arm --enable-gpl --disable-stripping --enable-avresample --disable-filter=resample --enable-avisynth --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libaom --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libcodec2 --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libjack --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libmysofa --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librsvg --enable-librubberband --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzmq --enable-libzvbi --enable-lv2 --enable-omx --enable-openal --enable-opengl --enable-sdl2 --enable-omx-rpi --enable-mmal --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libdrm --enable-libiec61883 --enable-chromaprint --enable-frei0r --enable-libx264 --enable-shared
  libavutil      56. 22.100 / 56. 22.100
  libavcodec     58. 35.100 / 58. 35.100
  libavformat    58. 20.100 / 58. 20.100
  libavdevice    58.  5.100 / 58.  5.100
  libavfilter     7. 40.101 /  7. 40.101
  libavresample   4.  0.  0 /  4.  0.  0
  libswscale      5.  3.100 /  5.  3.100
  libswresample   3.  3.100 /  3.  3.100
  libpostproc    55.  3.100 / 55.  3.100
Input #0, video4linux2,v4l2, from '/dev/video0':
  Duration: N/A, start: 40185.241073, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #0:0: Video: mjpeg, yuvj422p(pc, bt470bg/unknown/unknown), 640x480, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 1000k tbn, 1000k tbc
[segment @ 0x9800b0] Opening 'stream/looper00.avi' for writing
Output #0, segment, to 'stream/looper%02d.avi':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf58.20.100
    Stream #0:0: Video: mjpeg, yuvj422p(pc, bt470bg/unknown/unknown), 640x480, q=2-31, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 600 tbn, 1000k tbc
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (copy)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[segment @ 0x9800b0] Opening 'stream/looper01.avi' for writing/A speed=1.01x    
[segment @ 0x9800b0] Opening 'stream/looper02.avi' for writing/A speed=1.01x    
[avi @ 0x9822a0] Too large number of skipped frames 72034 > 60000speed=1.01x    
av_interleaved_write_frame(): Invalid argument
[avi @ 0x9822a0] Too large number of skipped frames 72034 > 60000
frame= 3011 fps= 25 q=-1.0 Lsize=N/A time=00:02:00.06 bitrate=N/A speed=1.01x
```

I did not find any suggestion to solve it.
Could you help me?

Thanks
Dario

Comment: See https://video.stackexchange.com/q/28446

Comment: @Gyan.You solved. THANKS!